# Trying to run "reg import C:\myRegKey.reg" as an admin within a script that runs as a standard user

Tags: powershell, windows-10, registry

I am working on a PowerShell script that sets up a user's profile after their Windows Profile has been created. The script performs various functions such as pinning items to the task bar, enabling offline files for the user's personal network drive, etc. I would like to include a reg import for MS Edge that forces the Favorites Bar to be enabled in order for Edge to feel more like IE once favorites have been transferred to the user's machine. I have the reg key created, but I need to apply admin rights to import the reg key.

I would prefer to not grant every user temp admin rights when their machine is built, and I would prefer to not have to manually enter credentials every time I run the script.

I was able to successfully pass my credentials to a PSCredential object, and I was able to run other cmdlets with said credentials. I am simply struggling to pass these credentials to a reg import.

Currently, I have two scripts. The main one that performs the tasks under the user profile, and the secondary one that prompts for admin rights and then performs the reg import. The main script currently calls the second script, which prompts for admin rights and imports the reg key.

#### Below is the portion of the main script that calls script number 2 to perform the admin task:

```
$Script = "\\NetworkDrive\Enable_Edge_Favorites_Bar.ps1"

&$Script
```

#### Script 2 is below:

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }

reg import "\\NetworkDrive\Edge_Favorites_Bar.reg"
```

While this is functional, I am looking for a way to do this where I do not need to enter a username and password each time. Ideally in a single script, but if someone has a solution that requires multiple scripts, I am willing to work with that as well!

I have tried:

```
Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -FilePath $Script
```

as well, but when I do, I receive an access denied error. So it seems that we do not have remote management turned on or at the very least I do not have access to perform remote registry edits.

I feel like I am most certainly just missing something stupid, so any assistance that someone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You say `I have the reg key created, but I need to apply admin rights to import the reg key.` But, why do you need to apply admin rights ? this key should be in HKCU, and the users can write almost everywhere in their HKCU

Comment: Most domains have the policy setting `Prevent Access To Registry Editing Tools` enabled. Is that what makes you think you need admin permissions?

Comment: The reg key that I am trying to import exists in HKLM, so it looks like I need admin rights to apply this to the whole machine. This is where I would be importing the key to: 

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\Main

As for what makes me think that I need admin rights. I receive an access denied error if I try to import the key this as the user outside of my script.